# Select from a table based on another table Number of records Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a unique requirement to select records from one table based on another table only if the second table has at least one record with a certain flag. The query should not return two records for the same ID: example:
Table 1

```
id  name    location
4   myname  MyLocation
6   hisname HisLocation
7   hername herlocation
```

The id in this table are unique:
Table two

```
id  details1   details2    closureflg
4   somdetails somedetails  Y
4   somdetails somedetails  Y
6   somdetails somedetails  N
7   somdetails somedetails  N
7   somdetails somedetail   N
```

I need to select from the first table one record only as long as the corresponding id has records in Table 2 whose closure flag is N:

I have tried:

```
select * from table1 where id in(select id from tbale2 where closureflg = 'N');
```

this returns two records for id 7;

My expected output:

```
id  name    location
6   hisname HisLocation
7   hername herlocation.
```

Please help.

Comment: Your query is working fine.. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78e1a/1

Comment: It is working for me too. What is the output are you getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please, try this one

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE closureflag = 'N' AND t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with a join

select id, name, location from table1 
   join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
   where table2.closureflg = 'N'
    group by id